# Android Studio 2.2.2.0 on Mac does not start

Tags: android-studio

I am having problems with all of the 2.2.x versions of Android Studio on my Mac.  I have downloaded the 2.2.2.0, and when I run the app, I can see the icon comes up in the Dock briefly, and then goes away.

**OS X:**
Yosemite (10.10.5)

**System Java:**
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
Note:  This is the ONLY JRE I have on my system

**Console Error:**
10/22/16 11:03:21.548 AM studio[953]: allVms required 1.8*,1.8+

10/22/16 11:03:21.552 AM studio[953]: Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3585 "The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture." (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture) UserInfo=0x7f845610 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try installing a universal version of the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk}

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time.

Comment: "allVms required 1.8*,1.8+" Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try install Java SE 1.8

Add JAVA_HOME to PATH in mac

```
$ touch .bash_profile
```

In bash_profile, add

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

You will see something like

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Then set ``/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home`` to the android studio JDK location

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android Studio v2.2 (AS) uses its own bundled OpenJDK 8, any other installed JDKs are not the issue.  The solution is to install AS (either dragging from the mounted DMG or unzipping) anywhere except the Applications folder.

For whatever reason, when AS resides in Applications, it raises the error posted in the question.  I would be very interested to know the reason, but after wasting countless hours, I am simply relieved it is running.